# File sent via header not working

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers, file-transfer

I'm using Laravel to get files and send back to the user for automatic download. This is my code:

```
public function postGetFile() {
    $inputData = $this->request->json()->all();

    try {
        $file = $this->processor->postGetFile($inputData);

        // Feed the file to web browser.
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($file));
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        if (ob_get_length()) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;

        return $this->response->success()->withData($file);
    } catch (ResponseException $e) {
        return $this->response->fail()->withException($e);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get the correct file back, but somehow the file is altered. The file size of the downloaded file is not the same as the original file on the server, so clearly something happens to the file in the transfer. Can anyone see what might go wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Tried the following, due to suggestion in comments:

```
public function postGetFile() {
    $inputData = $this->request->json()->all();

    try {
        $file = $this->processor->postGetFile($inputData);

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($file),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
        );

        // Tried both of the following, none worked.
        return response()->download($file, basename($file), $headers);
        return $this->response->download($file, basename($file), $headers);
    } catch (ResponseException $e) {
        return $this->response->fail()->withException($e);
    }
}
```

Only thing I get is the following error in console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://docker//admin/files/getfile. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9900' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

The Network tab does not give any data. Only "Failed to load response data".

Comment: Can you try add to headers "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"? If it'll not help try change header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9900"

Comment: A collegue of mine came up with a solution totally different from both our solutions, so I guess that will have to do :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel Http Response:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);

return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-downloads)

Comment: I have already tried that, but it is not working at all (I get no file at all). only error in console.